# Faithfully exact base-change and split extensions

Tags: ring-theory, modules, homological-algebra, noncommutative-algebra

Suppose $R \to S$ is a homomorphism of rings (unital, but not necessarily commutative) and $\mathcal{C}$ is an abelian subcategory of the category of left $R$-modules such that the functor $S \otimes_R -$ is *faithfully exact* when restricted to $\mathscr{C}$. (This means that a short exact sequence in $\mathcal{C}$ is exact if and only if its image under $S \otimes_R -$ is exact. See Ishikawa's [Faithfully Exact Functors...](https://projecteuclid.org/download/pdf_1/euclid.nmj/1118801336) for a few standard equivalent formulations.)

Does it then follow that an exact sequence

$$0 \to A \to B \to C \to 0$$

in $\mathcal{C}$ is split if and only if

$$0 \to F(A) \to F(B) \to F(C) \to 0$$

is split?

The "only if" dirction is obvious, so the question is about the "if" direction. If $R$ and $S$ are commutative and every $M \in \mathcal{C}$ is finitely presented, this is true and is proved in Hochster's lecture notes [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~hochster/711F07/L09.24.pdf). It seems like a very formal statement, but Hochster's lecture notes, it's proved by considering the base change map

$$S \otimes_R \mathrm{Hom}_R(-,-) \to \mathrm{Hom}_S(S \otimes_R -, S \otimes_R -),$$

which doesn't make sense for non-commutative $R$ and $S$.

For what I have in mind, $R$ and $S$ are not commutative. But they are relatively nice, so if it helps to assume the rings are left noetherian or left coherent or something along those lines, that's just fine.